# Search data inside Datagridview without database - VB.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, vb.net-2010

I've searched around and couldn't find the one I've been looking for.

I have a DataGridView in VB.NET with thousands of records from MySQL Database. Now, I want to SEARCH item_description that matches or something LIKE the inputted text. I am using TEXTCHANGED

I didn't use search to database since its taking time to load.

Sample is

`Search: orange`

DataGridView must filter and display only with the words like "orange"

| ITEM_ID | ITEM_DESCRIPTION |
| --- | --- |
| 120 | Orange Juice |
| 832 | Orange Fruit |

I am thinking of getting the array list names of the column "item_description" and filter it but I don't know where to start and what codes to use. Thank you

Comment: The grid should be irrelevant. You should query your database and populate a `DataTable` with the result set, bind that to a `BindingSource` and bind that to your grid. Both the `DataTable` and the `BindingSource` provides means to perfrom simple queries against the data and, for something more complex, you can perform a LINQ query against the `DataTable`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Hi, yes all the data being filtered was from a database. I will try this. Thank you so much for this suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have taken the advice in my comment and populated a `DataTable` and then bound that to the `DataGridView` via a `BindingSource`, filtering the data is a simple matter of setting the `Filter` property of that `BindingSource`. In your case, it should be something like this:

```vb
myBindingSource.Filter = "ITEM_DESCRIPTION LIKE 'orange*'"
```

One issue with filtering on the `TextChanged` event of a `TextBox` is that you will filter multiple times when the user types multiple characters when you only need the last one. To alleviate that, I suggest using a `Timer` that you start/restart each time a character is typed and then filter when it `Ticks`. That will enable the user to type multiple characters without filtering but also not have a significant wait after they stop typing for the filtering to be done. I recommend an interval of around 250 milliseconds but you can experiment to see what you think is best. E.g.

```vb
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    'Start/restart the Timer.
    Timer1.Stop()
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Timer1.Stop()

    'Perform the filtering.
    BindingSource1.Filter = $"ColumnName LIKE '{TextBox1.Text}*'"
End Sub
```